# Qt. Установка фокуса кнопке, при обработке keyPressEvent у Key_Down-Key_Up

Tags: c++, qt, события

Есть форма, на которой расположены несколько кнопок с именами "up", "down", и т.д

Необходимо обрабатывать нажатия на стрелки (key_up и т.д.).
Собственно сами ивенты я ловлю успешно таким вот образом.

```
bool ClientWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
        QKeyEvent *keyEvent = dynamic_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
        this->keyPressEvent(keyEvent);
    }
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

Проблема в том, что я хочу в *keyPressEvent* установить фокус у нужной кнопки, но:

1) Если я возвращаю из eventFilter при обработке нажатия **true**, то фокуса у кнопок вообще нет.

2) А если возвращаю **QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);**, то само собой setFocus в *keyPressEvent* работает не совсем как надо, так как в итоге фокус передается следующему объекту.

***Как обработать этот случай правильней всего?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переопределить функции `focusNextPrevChild()` у `ClientWindow`:

```
bool 
ClientWindow::
focusNextPrevChild(bool next)
{
    return false;
}
```

Реализация eventFilter() у меня:

```
bool
ClientWindow::
eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *e)
{
    if (e->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
    {
        if(watched->objectName() == "ClientWindowWindow") {
            ui->up->setStyleSheet("");    ui->down->setStyleSheet("");
            ui->left->setStyleSheet("");  ui->right->setStyleSheet("");
            QKeyEvent* event = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(e);
            switch(event->key()) {
            case Qt::Key_Up: ui->up->setFocus(); ui->up->setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid red;") ;break;
            case Qt::Key_Down: ui->down->setFocus(); ui->down->setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid red;"); break;
            case Qt::Key_Left: ui->left->setFocus(); ui->left->setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid red;"); break;
            case Qt::Key_Right: ui->right->setFocus(); ui->right->setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid red;"); break;
            }
        }
    }
    return QObject::eventFilter(watched, e);
}
```

Фильтр установить в конструкторе на qApp:

```
qApp->installEventFilter(this);
```

Comment: @Дмитрий глобальный указатель на объект текущего приложения типа `QApplication`

Comment: спасибо, работает. Правда фокус тогда становится "невидимым", то есть кнопка не выделяется пунктиром

Comment: @Дмитрий поэтому и styleSheet добавил